# maven-release-plugin deploy goal does not use custom settings.xml values

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin, maven-deploy-plugin

I think I found a strange problem with the maven goal "deploy" into maven-release-plugin execution.

When I build a release with custom settings (maven settings.xml) by using "-s" or "-gs" options, the inner goal "deploy" does not use custom settings (seems using `$M2_HOME/conf/settings.xml`). Is it a bug or I am doing something wrong ?
I have tried :

- `mvn release:prepare release:perform -s /opt/maven-3.0.4/conf/settings.xml`
- `mvn release:prepare release:perform -Darguments="-s /opt/maven-3.0.4/conf/settings.xml"`
- `mvn -DmavenHome=/opt/maven-3.0.4/ release:prepare release:perform`

Nothing works...

Debug :

```
[DEBUG] Using ${maven.home} of: '/opt/maven-3.0.4'.
[DEBUG] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /opt/jenkins/jobs/.../workspace && /opt/maven-3.0.4/bin/mvn -B -X -D maven.repo.local=/home/jenkins/.m2/repository -s /tmp/release-settings1555783726504175186.xml -D maven.test.skip=true clean install
[INFO] Apache Maven 3.0.4 (r1232337; 2012-01-17 09:44:56+0100)
[INFO] Maven home: /opt/maven-3.0.4-old
...
[INFO] [DEBUG] Reading global settings from /opt/maven-3.0.4-old/conf/settings.xml
[INFO] [DEBUG] Reading user settings from /tmp/release-settings1555783726504175186.xml
```

Comment: The first line `... -s /opt/...` should work. Try to run `mvn` with `-X` in addition  to the other arguments to get debug output. That should tell you which files Maven reads and why. Filter the output for `$M2_HOME/conf/settings.xml` to see when and how often is it read.

Comment: As you can see in debug mode, it's reading `Maven home: /opt/maven-3.0.4-old` (notice de *-old*) instead of using `${maven.home} of: '/opt/maven-3.0.4'`

Comment: Weird; can you try with a newer version of Maven?

Comment: I don't think that is a maven version problem but a maven-release-plugin problem, because a new shell `Executing: /bin/sh -c ...` is launched by the plugin and seems to cause this problem.

Comment: What is the whole command line that it's executing? Is it forwarding the environment and the `-s` option? Also check your environment variables; look for things like `MAVEN_OPTS`, `M2_HOME`, etc.

Comment: `M2_HOME` is set by the environement and it's wrong (and I cannot change it) that why I use `-s` option. The full command line is : `/bin/sh -c cd /opt/jenkins/jobs/.../workspace && /opt/maven-3.0.4/bin/mvn -B -X -D maven.repo.local=/home/jenkins/.m2/repository -s /tmp/release-settings1555783726504175186.xml -D maven.test.skip=true clean install` (and generated settings.xml use the settings.xml provided by `-s` option)

Comment: As you can see, the release plugin creates a new settings file. Maybe you can pause Maven and check the contents of this file? Also: Why can't you change the environement?

Comment: I can't change it, because I am not jenkins administrator... As you can see in my previous comment : "*generated settings.xml use the settings.xml provided by -s option*" (so it's the good settings.xml but why use old settings.xml in other goals...)

Comment: If you can install a script on the computer, then you can set the environment and then call Maven with `exec /opt/maven-3.0.4/bin/mvn "$@"`

Comment: I understand that change environement variable would be better (it's running into jenkins). But I don't understand why default settings are used even if `-s` option is provided !

Comment: Because `-s` changes only the user settings file which is usually `$HOME/.m2/settings.xml`. You also need to specify `-gs` to change the global/default settings file. It's possible that the deploy plugin doesn't pass this option on.